# Passing reference to char pointer is resulting in an error

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to pass a char & value to a char * argument in a function, but it's not working as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void change_sugar(const short& sugars, char* LOC);

int main()
{
    static int caga = 0;
    const short* mysweets;
    char& lala;
    change_sugar(mysweets, lala);
}
void change_sugar(const short& sugars, char** LOC[])
{
    if (sugars == 3000)
        LOC[1] = 5;
    cout << "Sugar is not nCaga, nor caga" << " ___  !@S ";
    cerr << "nCaga failed!";
}
```

Error output:

> error: `'lala'` declared as reference but not initialized

I am trying to pass a reference to a pointer of the same type. Is this correct?

Bear with me, I am new to C++, and I think I read the tutorial on pointers and references correctly.

EXTRA: I tried this with a different compiler, Turbo 16, I think, and it threw like ten other errors, so I don't know if it's a compiler problem or not.

Comment: I realize that passing the reference is useless, but I am just trying to practice getting pointers and references right, so I am "playing around" with this stuff until I put it to use.

Comment: Shouldn't your first question be "why does a reference variable need to be initialized"?

Comment: References must be bound (initialized) as the arey created; the binding cannot be changed after the reference is created.  Your compiler is complaining correctly.  And there's not much chance that a `char &` could ever be passed legitimately to a function expecting `char **[]`.  That's a nasty function parameter at the best of times — look up Three-Star Programmer to see why.

Comment: The definition of `change_sugar()` conflicts with the earlier declaration. You declared it as taking `char *LOC`, but the definition says `char **LOC[]`, which is equivalent to `char ***LOC`. I'm surprised you're not getting errors about that.

Comment: It takes a char *, not a triple pointer!

Comment: @Barmar: It dones't conflict, because C++ supports function overloading. The first declaration is for a different function than the definition that is below `main()`.

Comment: Your code currently says the second argument is `char** LOC[]`, and that _is_ equivalent to `char ***LOC`.  It may not be what you intended to say, but it is what your code currently says.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yeah, I think there are many errors being emitted by the compiler, but the OP is only showing one of them for some reason.

Comment: No, I am only getting one. I got 3 warning, but no other erros

Comment: @user2946290: Then you have a faulty compiler. Use a better one. See [this](http://ideone.com/omdbhu).

Answer (score 0):

In C++ a reference must always be valid (and not "dangling"), so you have to initalize it when creating it.

I am not sure what you wanted to do with your `lala`, but a proper usage of a reference variable is like so:

```
char a;
char & b = a; // has to be initialized here
```

Now you can use `b` wherever a variable of type `char` is meant to be used. *However*, your function wants `char *` as its second parameter.

Thus, after initializing the reference, you could still use its address to make it fit: `&lala`.

Also your definition and declaration is mismatched.

Comment: Huh? I do not understand why would I point to the address of lala to mysweets? The problem is passing lala to the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things wrong with your code.

A reference and a pointer are not the same thing in the C++ language, although they are implemented the same way in the compiled machine code.  You cannot pass a reference where a pointer is expected, and vice versa.  You are trying to pass a `short*` where a `short&` is expected, and a `char&` where a `char*` is expected.

A reference can never be uninitialized (hense the compiler error), but a pointer can be uninitialized.

The parameters in your `change_sugar()` declaration do not match the parameters in the definition.  In C++, they must match.

It is very unclear what `change_sugar()` is actually trying to do.  Clearly, you want to alter the `char` that is passed in, but `char` is only 1 byte in size and you are trying to alter memory past the 1-byte boundary of the data being altered.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void change_sugar(const short& sugars, char* LOC);

int main()
{
    short mysweets = 3000;
    char lala = 0;
    change_sugar(mysweets, &lala);
}

void change_sugar(const short& sugars, char* LOC)
{
    if ((LOC) && (sugars == 3000))
        *LOC = 5;
    cout << "Sugar is not nCaga, nor caga" << " ___  !@S ";
    cerr << "nCaga failed!";
}
```

Or this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void change_sugar(const short& sugars, char& LOC);

int main()
{
    short mysweets = 3000;
    char lala = 0;
    change_sugar(mysweets, lala);
}

void change_sugar(const short& sugars, char& LOC)
{
    if (sugars == 3000)
        LOC = 5;
    cout << "Sugar is not nCaga, nor caga" << " ___  !@S ";
    cerr << "nCaga failed!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a very simple paradigm for passing variables to methods wanting pointers:

```
void clear(char *p) { *p = '\0'; }

char c = 'a';
clear(&c);     // after this call c == '\0'
```

Are you actually looking for something more advanced here?

Reference variables:

```
char &r = c;
```

Are actually pretty complicated.  (And would still be passed with `&r`)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that bothers me with the code so I'll go through some them.

**1: Your prototype does not match.**

Change

`void change_sugar(const short& sugars, char** LOC[])`

to

`void change_sugar(const short& sugars, char* LOC)`

or the other way around depending on what you actually want to do.

**2. Your pointer is not initialized.**

`const short* mysweets` is not initialized. Allocate some memory for it.

`const short* mysweets = malloc(sizeof(short));`

then

`*mysweets = 3000;`

**3. lala is not a pointer.**

If you want to pass the address of `lala` to your function, `change_sugar`, initialize it as so

`char* lala = malloc(sizeof(char));`

and pass it as

`change_sugar(mysweets, lala);`

If you don't want it to be a pointer but still want to pass by reference, declare it as so

`char lala;`

and pass it as

`change_sugar(mysweets, &lala);`

**Finally:**

Your code is very confusing to read and to figure out what you actually want to do. I suggest to step back and think about what you want to achieve and redesign your code.